# Can't Create Actionbar in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create `actionbar` with back button but it doesn't show up

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu) {
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ActionBarMenu, menu);
    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item) {
    this.Finish();
    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

that's actionbar xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id = "@+id/actionBack"
        android:icon ="@drawable/arrow_l_black"
        android:title="Back"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure, you are inflating the right resource? Shouldn't be Resource.Menu.actionbar?

Comment: but xml file name is ActibarMenu.
http://i.imgur.com/21Kzzig.png

Comment: Are you testing on a device with a hardware menu button? What happens if you press it?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I'm testing with genymotion emulator.

Comment: What API level are you using for both the emulator and for the minimum target of your app?

Comment: @Cheesebaron 19 for both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to show the back button and you are using API 14+, then you can simply do this:

```
[Activity(Label = "Main", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        button.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof (SecondActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }
}

[Activity(Label = "Second", ParentActivity = typeof(MainActivity))]
public class SecondActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                NavigateUpTo(ParentActivityIntent);
                break;
        }

        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So what happens is that `MainActivity` launches `SecondActivity` when pressing the button. In `OnCreate` of `SecondActivity` you request that a back button is displayed. Then in `OnOptionsItemSelected` you wait for `Android.Resource.Id.Home` is the id of the item pressed. This is the default Id of the back button. When this happens you call the built in `NavigateUpTo` method (this is in NavUtils when using Support v4 on lower API levels) to tell the `Activity` to navigate up to the `ParentActivity` set in the `Activity` attribute flags.

`ParentActivity` is set through `MetaData` attribute flag on lower than API 14, API levels like so:

```
[Activity(...)]
[MetaData("android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY", Value = "app9.MainActivity")]
public class SecondActivity : Activity { ... }
```

Where `app9` is my namespace lowercased.

Using the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` to inflate a menu from an XML file is used to create additional `ActionBar` items. In this case it would create a button on the right side with a back arrow or whatever you have defined your `@drawable/arrow_l_black` `Drawable` to be.